# TypeScript error: ';' expected when using "let" keyword

Tags: typescript

I'm taking my first steps into TypeScript and discovered `let` keyword, which I found very helpful.

However, TypeScript compiler throws `error TS1005: ';' expected.` when trying to compile the following code:

```
let one = 1;
```

The command I use to compile is `$ tsc file.tsc`

Any help you can provide will be great!

Comment: what version of `tsc`?

Comment: this seems weird, are you sure it complains about this line of code? can you post some more of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a *really really old* version of TypeScript (at least in TypeScript term of long) e.g. `1.0.1` will give that error as it does not understand `let`:

[image]

Please use a newer TypeScript version such as 1.8

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was the exact problem I was having :)

Answer (score 0):

There was Environment path to Typescript 1.0 from Windows SDK on my machine. Removing that will solve this issue in VS Code terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677437/how-to-update-typescript-to-latest-version-with-npm) to update the typescript and point to the right version in PATH.
I faced the same issue even after updating the typescript because I had another version installed by Visual studio. And PATH was pointing to that old version like below.

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js

Open Cmd and do 'where tsc' , which shows the list of typescripts in the path then you can manually delete the typescript paths outside of nodejs. Credits - [evilinside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400677/evilinside)