# How to update TypeScript to latest version with npm?

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

Currently I have TypeScript 1.0.3.0 version installed on my machine.
I want to update it to latest one i.e. 2.0.

How to do this with npm?

Comment: specifying exact version worked for me, like this:    `npm install typescript@2.9.2`

Answer (score 473, accepted):

Try `npm install -g typescript@latest`. You can also use `npm update` instead of install,  without the latest modifier.

Comment: I have tried it on windows command prompt. I'm using Microsoft's visual studio code.

Comment: If you type "npm list -g", what version of TypeScript appears?

Comment: Oops! I'm using latest one only 2.1.0. I was mistakenly considered `tsc -v ` as `TypeScript` version as it was showing 1.0

Comment: Open Cmd and do  'where tsc' , which shows the list of typescripts in the path then you can manually delete the typescript paths outside of nodejs. This trick worked for me after hours frustration while updating to typescript 2.2.2.

Comment: My typescript is updated but I still can't generate "tsc --init"

Comment: @EvilInside This finally got it working for me too! You should consider editing the answer to include your comment.

Comment: npm update -g typescript doens't work instead, just for pick  up note

Comment: In linux you still need to check if the executable /usr/bin/tsc is the same as /home/<you-user>/.nvm/versions/node/<version>/bin/tsc (or whatelse it is the npm global destination). Sometimes 'npm install -g' does not update the executable (tsc) in /usr/bin

Answer (score 120):

**Open command prompt (cmd.exe/git bash)**

Recommended:

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

or

```
yarn global add typescript@latest  // if you use yarn package manager
```

This will install the latest typescript version **if not already installed**,
**otherwise it will update** the current installation to the latest version.

And then **verify** which version is installed:

```
tsc -v
```

[image]

---

If you have typescript already installed you could also use the following command to update to latest version, but as commentators have reported and I confirm it that the following command does not update to latest (as of now [ `Feb 10 '17`])!

```
npm update -g typescript@latest
```

Comment: tsc -v command not recognized,  tried

npm ls typescript
module-ui@0.1.0 /Users/.../Repo/module-ui
└── typescript@3.9.7

Answer (score 37):

If you are on Windows and have Visual Studio installed you might have something in your PATH that is pointing to an old version of TypeScript.  I found that removing the folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\" from my PATH (or deleting/renaming this folder) will allow the more recent npm globally installed TypeScript version of tsc to work.

Comment: Opening a cmd prompt and typing 'where tsc' will show you where it is installed to

Comment: Thank you Veener I had the exact same issue and your comment help me fix it by deleting the 1.0 version folder of TypeScript.

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to do this by simply typing `npm install -g typescript@2.0`. If this does not work, I am beginning to wonder what version of node and npm you are on. Try `node -v` and `npm -v` to find these out. You should be on node >4.5 and npm >3

Comment: If you have a older version of npm, use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows

Answer (score 4):

For **npm**:
you can run:

```
npm update -g typescript
```

By default, it will install latest version.

For **yarn**, you can run:

```
yarn upgrade typescript
```

Or you can remove the orginal version, run `yarn global remove typescript`, and then execute `yarn global add typescript`, by default it will also install the latest version of typescript.

more details, you can read [yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/).

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this error was to update the typescript version with this command:

`npm install -g typescript@latest` as I was using Windows.
However on Mac this can also be doable by `sudo npm install -g typescript@latest`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the command `# npm update -g typescript` 
For update all global installed module, Use this command`# npm update -g`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows with very old NodeJS, then uninstall previous NodeJs and NVM (Node Version Manager) in Control Panel (Win7) or Settings/Apps (Win10) if exists.
Make sure that they are removed from the PATH.

Reinstall NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/en/download
It will install NPM as well.

Install TypeScript globally:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Verify installation:

```
tsc -v
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `where` in prompt to find the current executable in path

```
C:\> where tsc
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

If your **system already installs typescript globally** you just need to update the typescript version.

Make sure to check your typescript version first.

```
tsc -v
```

or

```
tsc
```

tsc command gives you more details.

If everything is configured properly and there are no issues. You only need to upgrade your typescript version at this point.

```
npm update -g typescript
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Next install the latest version of typescript globally with

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

After it's done, type

```
tsc -v
```

to see the latest version of typescript installed in your system.