# Why `npm update -g` is not updating my global packages to the latest version?

Tags: npm

I'm following steps from [updating global packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages), so I executed `npm outdated -g --depth=0` and  got:

```
Package     Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
typescript    2.2.2   2.2.2   2.4.1
```

Then, I executed `npm update -g`, but I still got the same output from `npm outdated -g --depth=0`.

Executing `npm list -g --depth=0` also confirms that the typescript package has not been updated to 2.4.1:

```
+-- bower@1.8.0
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- typescript@2.2.2
`-- typings@2.1.1
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of npm are you using? Versions before 2.6.1 cannot update all globally. You can however update them one by one by doing  `npm update -g <package>`

Comment: My npm version is 3.10.10

Comment: Official ref https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update TypeScript to latest version with npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677437/how-to-update-typescript-to-latest-version-with-npm)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to either use [this script](https://gist.github.com/othiym23/4ac31155da23962afd0e) or do them one by one it seems.

This global update is a known breaking point.
[Here is the reference to this issue. They seem to have closed it without addressing the issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11534)

Comment: Got it. It seems the scripts simply does `npm -g install <package>` for each package. So I typed that on the Windows console and it updated each package to its latest version. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can also install specific version:

```
npm install -g typescript@2.4.1
```

Answer (score 3):

### As of now, there is no one simple command that does this.

You can use the following steps instead to find outdated packages and update them one by one.

1. **Determining which global packages need updating:** To see which global packages need to be updated, on the command line, run:

   ```
   npm outdated -g --depth=0
   ```
2. **Updating a single global package:** To update a single global package, on the command line, run:

   ```
   npm update -g <package_name>
   ```

Comment: Any idea why there is no longer a way to update all packages in a single command?

Answer (score 2):

**To automatically update all global packages to the 'Latest' version in a single command:**

```
npx npm-check --global --update-all
```

*That will update all global packages to the 'Latest' version*. [More information is available about npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check), including the ability to perform an interactive update, exclude packages, etc.

---

Conversely, `npm update -g` only updates global packages to the 'Wanted' version shown by `npm outdated --global`, as globally installed packages are treated as if they are installed with a caret semver range specified.

---

Lastly, if you happen to want to update (install) a package to a version *other* than 'Latest' or 'Wanted':

```
npm install --global <pkg>@<version>
```