# Typescript refusing to update version

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am running into an issue installing the desired version of typescript onto my laptop. When I install typescript using the command on the command line:

npm install typescript@3.3.4000 -g

It appears to install something as packages are added, but when I check the typescript version by typing:

tsc -v

It shows me that the version is still 1.0.3.0

I have tried using the command

npm uninstall typescript -g

but this doesn't seem to be removing the 1.0.3.0 version, it only removes newer versions that I added. The 1.0.3.0 version seems to have taken root and doesn't want to go away. How can I fix this?

I expect to see "Version 3.3.4000"
instead I keep seeing "Version 1.0.3.0"

How can I get the desired typescript version?

Comment: What does `which tsc` show you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update TypeScript to latest version with npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677437/how-to-update-typescript-to-latest-version-with-npm)