# TypeScript error TS1005: ';' expected (II)

Tags: typescript

First of all, I've already seen the other posts about error TS1005. *Same error code, but totally different.*

A simple `let x: number;` will generate the `error TS1005` during compilation. It's not about a missing semicolon as what the error message says, but the compiler does not recognize the let keyword. I read that maybe because of an outdated compiler.

Here's my typescript version installed using `npm install -g typescript`

- TypeScript version: `2.5.2`
- Compiler (tsc) version: `1.0.3.0`

*Maybe somebody can help?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript error: ';' expected when using "let" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899390/typescript-error-expected-when-using-let-keyword)

Comment: No. This is an error from Typescript because npm installs the wrong version. I opened [an issue about it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21510). @StockUberflow Please support it.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Your installation is wrong; you are using a very old compiler version (1.0.3.0).

`tsc --version` should return a version of 2.5.2.

Check where that old compiler is located using: `which tsc` (or `where tsc`) and remove it.

Try uninstalling the "global" typescript

```
npm uninstall -g typescript
```

Installing as part of a local dev dependency of your project

```
npm install typescript --save-dev
```

Execute it from the root of your project

```
./node_modules/.bin/tsc
```

Comment: Hi sir, solved it. Thank you. The key is `which tsc` or `where tsc`. Found out there was another version of tsc in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\. I just removed the old one from the path.

Comment: Opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21510) about it.

Comment: I was using a slightly older version of tsc which led to not existing issues. I updated the global tsc and now it is okay.

Comment: This worked awesome. I was using `npx tsc <filename>` to compile. Weird that `npx` would use an outdated version?

Comment: @StockUberflow I can't find any other version nor can I find the Microsoft SDKs folder? Will you help me after 6 years?

Answer (score 20):

**On Windows** you can have in your PATH

```
PATH = ...;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\; ...
```

remove it from PATH env, then

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

it worked for me to solve the

> "TypeScript error TS1005: ';' expected"

See also [how to update TypeScript to latest version with npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677437/how-to-update-typescript-to-latest-version-with-npm)

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me. I think you have to restart your PC. My OS was windows 7.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have the last version of typescript.

Running :

```
npm install -g typescript
```

`npm` checks if `tsc` command is already installed.

And **it might be**, by another software like `Visual Studio`. If so, `npm` doesn't override it. So you have to remove the previous deprecated `tsc` installed command.

Run `where tsc` to know its bin location. It should  be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\` in windows. Once found, delete the folder, and re-run `npm install -g typescript`. *This should now install the last version of typescript.*

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same error. After banging my head for half an hour, I found one Romeo bracket hanging around without his Juliet LOL...!(the opening and closing brackets were mismatching)
Please check all your brackets to avoid such errors.

Comment: in my case, I had two cases like as your explanation.
But after all, I found syntax error exists in my code.
  
1. missing `,` after vue function declration.  
2. missiing > in the async function promis recturn value

Answer (score 3):

> The issue was in my code.

In large code base, issue was not clear.

A simplified code is below:

**Bad:**

```
 collection.insertMany(
    [[],
    function (err, result) {
    }
 );
```

**Good:**

```
collection.insertMany(
    [],
    function (err, result) {
    }
 );
```

That is, the first one has `[[]`, instead of normal array `[]`

TS error was not clear enough, and it showed error in the last line with `}  )`;

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had today a similar error message. What was peculiar is that it did not break the Application. It was running smoothly but the command prompt (Windows machine) indicated there was an error. 
I did not update the Typescript version but found another culprit. 
It turned there was a tiny omission of symbol - closing ")", which I believe The Typescript is compensating for. Just for reference the code is the following:

```
[new Object('First Characteristic','Second Characteristic',
'Third Characteristic'*] 

* notice here the ending ")" is missing.
```

Once brought back no more issues on the command prompt!

Comment: Did not mean to downvote, but apparently there is no undo for that.

Comment: If you click the downvote button again it will undo it. Or you can click upvote

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0` directory.
- Now run :

  ```
  npm install -g typescript
  ```

  this will install the latest version and then re-try.

Comment: I don't have that Microsoft SDKs folder :(

Answer (score 1):

Just try to without changing anything
`npm install rxjs@X.X.X`
X.X.X is your current version

Answer (score 0):

I was injecting service like this:

```
private messageShowService MessageShowService
```

instead of:

```
private messageShowService: MessageShowService
```

and that was the reason of error, despite nothing related with `','` was there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `error TS1005: 'finally' expected.`, it means you forgot to implement `catch` after `try`. Generally, it means the syntax you attempted to use was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid issue with minor mistake;

i was trying

```
const quizType = computed(() => rootState.quizzes.quiz

const res = await noAuthApi.getQuizzes(quizType)
```

and the issue was, i missed the closing bracket.  it should be like

```
const quizType = computed(() => rootState.quizzes.quiz)

const res = await noAuthApi.getQuizzes(quizType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify extension of file. File containing `tsx` should have `.tsx` extension.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I'd the 'function' keyword. I'd to remove it.

**Bad**:

export class CustomValidators {

static function myFunc(x: string) { console.log(x) }
}

**Good**:

export class CustomValidators {

static myFunc(x: string) { console.log(x) }
}

Answer (score 0):

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PyZw.png)

In my case the **Import type** supported on typescript version 3.8 or above, but I install lower version of **ngx-tour-core** that doesn't contain **Import type** and problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mine was solved with this.

```
// TS1005
constructor(
  @Inject('USER_SERVICE') private readonly 
  userService: UsersService,
) { }

// No Error
constructor(
  @Inject('USER_SERVICE') private readonly userService: UsersService,
) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

update typescript version from 3.x ->4.4.4 .Solve my problem

Answer (score -2):

There may be a conflict with both of the packages "tsc" & "typescript" due to the fact that they both use the same command `tsc index.ts`

`tsc` is deprecated, hence you should only use `typescript`:

`> npm install -g typescript`

`> tsc ./index.ts`