# @ngx-share share button does not work in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-share

I am using a Facebook share button in my angular 6 project, found [here](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons/wiki/Share-Button-Directive) . This should supposed to "Convert any element to a share button using [shareButton] directive.".

According to the instructions, I do

`npm i -S @ngx-share/core @angular/cdk`

with no errors

In my `app.module.ts` I do `import { ShareModule } from '@ngx-share/core';` and then I put `HttpClientModule` and `ShareModule` in my Imports.

Then I put this button in my template `<button shareButton="facebook">Share</button>`. No errors here.

But if I do `ng serve` again, I get

```
ERROR in node_modules/@ngx-share/core/lib/share.service.d.ts(12,26): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@ngx-share/core/lib/share.service.d.ts(13,5): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
node_modules/@ngx-share/core/lib/share.service.d.ts(14,21): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@ngx-share/core/lib/share.service.d.ts(14,42): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/@ngx-share/core/lib/share.service.d.ts(14,48): error TS1109: Expression expected.
node_modules/@ngx-share/core/lib/share.service.d.ts(15,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

What am I missing here? How can I make this work for angular 6 ? The instructions for angular 6 look the same. What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: Please see if this solution helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46399668/1727357

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install --save @angular/cdk@6
npm install --save @ngx-share/core@6
```