# getting TS1005 typescript error after runing npm start in nestjs project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I ran a nodejs project that use nestjs.
after installing all packages with npm install and runing npm `run start` command 
I got this error and I searched many times but I didn't find any solution.
here is error

```
E:\project\node_modules\@types\mongodb\index.d.ts(935,21)
      TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I tried with 2 typescript versions 2.7.1 and 3.6 but it didn't work.

here is some information about my system and that project:

**OS**: win10 x64 however I tried it with Ubuntu18

**typescript version**: I tried with 2.7 and 3.6 versions and I got the same error

**monogdb version**:3.5.6.[mongodb package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell why this happens exactly with the information you provided, however as a workaround you can try skipping the [check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) of all declarations files by setting the following option in your `tsconfig`:

```
{
...
skipLibCheck: true
...
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. what information is needed I'll  add it.

Comment: So you're on a Ubuntu VM on windows? Did you remove the node_modules folder and execute npm --install? Also this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46399668/3761628