# typescript error ts1005 ' ' expected i tried all possible solutions and resources and didn't work

Tags: typescript, npm

I've followed this thread to solve the problem

[TypeScript error TS1005: ';' expected (II)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398916/typescript-error-ts1005-expected-ii/47960532)

I installed Typescript as global but it always saved at `C:/Users/MyName/AppData/Roaming/npm`

I'm not sure if this should be global so I used `npm update` then `npm uninstall -g typescript` then `npm install -g typescript@latest`.

My environment last variable has

```
C:\Users\Mostafa\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

I tried to execute the code from the source so I used in the VS Code

```
cd C:\Users\Mostafa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin
```

then

```
tsc C:\Users\Mostafa\HelloWorld\src\index.ts
```

Also didn't work

Comment: Hi Mostafa please include your typescript code and all errors you encounter.

Comment: I'm totally new to typescript but these snippets from a book
`addTodo(task: string): number {
            while (this.getTodoById(this.nextId)) {
            this.nextId++;
            }
            this.todoItems.push(new TodoItem(this.nextId, task));
            return this.nextId;
            };`

and this the error

`./../../HelloWorld/src/todoItem.ts:32:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

32         addTodo(task: string): number {`

Comment: Two things I found in your code: 1. If you are creating a function you need to place `function` at beginning of your function definition `function addTodo(...){...}` 2. You don't need semicolon at the end of your function definition

Comment: @MMD Yeah, thanks it ran, it's just first time i write typescript code and i'm learning from Essential TypeScript : From Beginner to Pro and it starts with some projects 
Thank you it wasn't the compiler problem