# Error with @reduxjs/toolkit and Typescript - TS1005

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

After installing the required packages to run react-redux and @reduxjs//toolkit in my current projects, I ran into this error after running npm start:

```
TypeScript error in C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/node_modules/@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/configureStore.d.ts(1,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005
 1 | import type { Reducer, ReducersMapObject, Middleware, Action, AnyAction, StoreEnhancer, Store, Dispatch, PreloadedState, CombinedState } from 'redux';
```

My store is this:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import securityReducer from "../features/security/securitySlice.js";
const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      security: securityReducer,
  },
  });
export default store;
```

My index.tsx file contains this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`
import "./index.css";`
import AppContainer from "./AppContainer.js";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import store from "./app/store.jsx";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppContainer />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And my package.json file is this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.0.3",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js-typescript": "^1.22.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.0.2",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.799.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-ui-dropzone": "^3.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "rc-slider": "~9.2.4",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-google-charts": "^3.0.15",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-ts": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false --coverage",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
    "test:watch": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/rc-slider": "~8.6.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.18",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1"
  }
}
```

I read from some posts that my version of typescript needed to be updated to 3.8 but it still doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Thank you so much if anyone knows how to fix this error.

Comment: Try deleting and installing the typescript dependency; https://stackoverflow.com/a/46399668

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can upgrade your typescript version to "^4.1.2", I also have the same problem with you, and I fix that with this