# How to fix ERROR in node_modules/chart.js/types/animation.d.ts(20,37): error TS1005: ',' expected. in chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular6

I am working on an Angular 6 project where I want to create some charts using chart.js.

I installed chart.js using npm install chart.js and its version is like 3.5.1.

My TypeScript version is like 2.9.0.

So when I try to `ng serve`:

```
node_modules/chart.js/types/animation.d.ts(20,37): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/animation.d.ts(20,46): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(39,56): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(39,58): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(39,85): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(535,38): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(535,56): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2424,37): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2424,50): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2734,63): error TS1005: ';' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2734,69): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2738,22): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2742,63): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2746,57): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2746,68): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2746,75): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2746,76): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2763,26): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2767,67): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2771,56): error TS1005: '(' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2771,67): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2771,73): error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2771,74): error TS1005: ')' expected.
node_modules/chart.js/types/index.esm.d.ts(2788,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

What is this and how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I think your installation is not correct. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398916/typescript-error-ts1005-expected-ii/46399668)

Comment: @JsNgian As this is an ongoing project everyone using ts 2.9.2, So if I upgrade that would that be any crash?

Comment: Then you cannot update. Is it working properly for others?

Comment: @JsNgian, This Dashboard chart creation task is given to me so, I am the one who is responsible for this. So that is the matter here with

Comment: Try version 3.0.2

Comment: I Update the version in package.json and enter npm update, but the same issue raising. Maybe. Why does this happen?

Comment: @JsNgian I just downgrade the version of  2.7.3. So now it's working fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have stated, downgrading to chart.js version 2.7.3 fixed this for me. For anyone not super familiar with npm, here's the commands I used to update the package:

```
npm remove chart.js --save
npm install chart.js@2.7.3 --save
```

I specifically did this for my ionic 5 project. But it should also work for angular.

Answer (score 3):

I try out several solutions but could not find them, So I just downgrade the chartjs 3.5.1 to 2.7.3. So it is working fine.