# SPFx solution deployment failure

Tags: reactjs, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, spfx

I'm trying to Deploy my SPFX Solution using CI/CD Pipeline.

While running the pipeline it is throwing me this error with react-select File. The error message is the below:

> Error - tsc node_modules/react-select/dist/declarations/src/accessibility/index.d.ts(1,13): error TS1005: '=' expected

Can someone help me with this?  Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please share a bit more info about the packages that you use and at which step of the build(i'm geussing its in the building stage) is failing?
Usually, such kind of errors are non-matching versions between typescript and types file used. As you can see from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46399668/8894067 you might need to reconfigure your typescript version

Comment: Similar posted here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17459 . The possible solution indicates to check the current TypeScript version you are using.